# extract highest and lowest values for columns in R, as well as row identifiers

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have some data of the following kind:

```
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*10000, 1, .5), ncol=10))
```

I want a new dataframe that keeps the 10 original columns, but for every column retains only the highest 10 and lowest 10 values. Importantly, the rows have names corresponding to id values that need to be kept in the new data frame.

Thus, the end result data.frame is gonna be of dimensions m by 10, where m is very likely to be more than 20. But for every column, I want only 20 valid values.

The only way I can think of doing this is doing it manually per column, using `dplyr` and arrange, grabbing the top and bottom rows, and then creating a matrix from all the individual vectors. Clearly this is inefficient. Help?

Comment: First, dplyr is for use with data.frames, not matrices. Also, if there are row names you want preserved, why not show that in the example?

Comment: Will fix references to matrices, although all I want to keep is the row identifier which may be a number.

Comment: Can you please show an example. I am also confused with the row names thing.

Comment: You can add your row numbers as a variable; use reshape2::melt or something similar to convert to long format; sort; slice/filter to the top and bottom rows within each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep all the rows from the original dataset, where there is at least one value satisfying your condition (value among ten largest or ten smallest in the given column), you could do it like this:

```
# create a data frame
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*10000, 1, .5), ncol=10))
# function to find lowes 10 and highest 10 values
lowHigh <- function(x)
{
        test <- x
        test[!(order(x) <= 10 | order(x) >= (length(x)- 10))] <- NA
        test
}
# apply the function defined above
test2 <- apply(df, 2, lowHigh)
# use the original rownames
rownames(test2) <- rownames(df)
# keep only rows where there is value of interest
finalData <- test2[apply(apply(test2, 2, is.na), 1, sum) < 10, ]
```

Please note that there is definitely some smarter way of doing it...

Comment: This is exactly right. It creates a new data frame that preserves rownames, and each row has at least one valid observation. My data is from a sort of massive factor analysis, so in the new dataframe I can see which rows are loading onto particular factors. thanks!

Comment: @ricatom How is this accurate? It doesn't' return 20 values per column. It's also going to be substantially slower than my method. I'll add the benchmark to my answer.

Comment: Noone asked for 20 rows. See the 3rd paragraph in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data matrix with 10 highest and 10 lowest in each column,

```
x<-apply(df,2,function(k) k[order(k,decreasing=T)[c(1:10,(length(k)-9):length(k))]])
```

x is your 20 by 10 matrix.
Your requirement of rownames is conflicting column by column, altogether you only have 20 rownames in this matrix and it can not be same for all 10 columns. Instead, here is your order matrix,

```
x_roworder<-apply(df,2,function(k) order(k,decreasing=T)[c(1:10,(length(k)-9):length(k))])
```

This will give you corresponding rows in original data matrix within each column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're expecting for your return / output. But this will get you the appropriate indices

```
# example data
set.seed(41234L)
N <- 1000
df<-data.frame(id= 1:N, matrix(rnorm(10*N, 1, .5), ncol=10))

# for each column, extract ID's for top 10 and bottom 10 values
l1 <- lapply(df[,2:11], function(x,y, n) {
  xy <- data.frame(x,y)
  xy <- xy[order(xy[,1]),]
  return(xy[c(1:10, (n-9):n),2])
}, y= df[,1], n = N)

# check: 
xx <- sort(df[,2])
all.equal(sort(df[l1[[1]], 2]), xx[c(1:10, 991:1000)])
[1] TRUE
```

If you want an m * 10 matrix with these unique values, where m is the number of unique indices, you could do:

```
l2 <- do.call("c", l1)
l2 <- unique(l2)

df2 <- df[l2,] # in this case, m == 189
```

This doesn't `0` / `NA` the columns which you're not searching on for each row. But it's unclear what your question is trying to do.

#### Note

This isn't as efficient as using `data.table` since you're going to get a copy of the data in `xy <- data.frame(x,y)`

#### Benchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ira= {
  test2 <- apply(df[,2:11], 2, lowHigh);
  rownames(test2) <- rownames(df);
  finalData <- test2[apply(apply(test2, 2, is.na), 1, sum) < 10, ]
},
alex= {
  l1 <- lapply(df[,2:11], function(x,y, n) {
    xy <- data.frame(x,y)
    xy <- xy[order(xy[,1]),]
    return(xy[c(1:10, (n-9):n),2])
  }, y= df[,1], n = N);


  l2 <- unique(do.call("c", l1));
  df2 <- df[l2,]
}, times= 50L)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  ira 4.360452 4.522082 5.328403 5.140874 5.560295 8.369525    50   b
 alex 3.771111 3.854477 4.054388 3.936716 4.158801 5.654280    50  a
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer a couple of answers to this.

A base R implementation ( I have used `%>%` to make it easier to read)

```
ix = lapply(df, function(x) order(x)[-(1:(length(x)-20)+10)]) %>%
  unlist %>% unique %>% sort

df[ix,]
```

This abuses the fact that data frames are lists, finds the row id satisfying the condition for each column, then takes the unique ones in order as the row indices you want to keep. This should retain any row names attached to `df`

An alternative using `dplyr` (since you mentioned it) which if I remember correctly doesn't particular like row names

```
# add id as a variable
df$id = 1:nrow(df) # or row names
df %>% 
    gather("col",value,-id) %>% 
    group_by(col) %>% 
    filter(min_rank(value) <= 10 | min_rank(desc(value)) <= 10) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(id) %>% 
    left_join(df)
```

Edited: To fix code alignment and make a neater `filter`